# Vector equality proof

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, vectors

> Prove that for all vectors $a,b$:
>   $$|a×b|\le|a||b|$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

If the angle formed by the vectors ${\bf a}$ and ${\bf b}$  is $\theta$, then:

$$\left\| {\bf a} \times {\bf b} \right\| = |{\bf a}| |{\bf b}| \sin\theta$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Do I substitute the RHS into the inequality, and then we know Sin(theta) is always between 1 and -1, therefore the equality holds?

Comment: @Zain But you don't want to show that an _equality_ holds, you're trying to show an _inequality_. But yes, the key idea is now to use $\sin \theta \le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use the sine formula you can use this one

(a,b,c)*(x,y,z)=(bz-yc,cx-za,ay-bx)

Now use |(a,b,c)|^2=a^2+b^2+c^2